# Ler conteúdo de vários arquivos .txt's de uma determinada pasta

Tags: php

Tenho este código que lê um arquivo criado por `Netscape HTTP Cookie File`, porém eu só consegui utilizar o script e ler o arquivo do usuário que está com a sessão `username` aberta, eu preciso listar todos os `TXTS` e ler todos eles sem exceção.

OBS: os arquivos estão com nomes diferentes:

```
<?php

require_once getcwd() . '/modules/config.php';

$username = null;

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}

$pointer = fopen(getcwd() . '/cookies/' . $username . '.txt', 'r');

while (!feof($pointer)) {
    $row = fgets($pointer);
}

fclose($pointer);
```

Como ler todos os arquivos com nomes diferentes sem ser o arquivo com o nome criado na sessão ?

**EDITADO**

Nos comentários o Anderson citou o uso da função `glob()`, eu consegui ler todos os arquivos com este código.

```
foreach (glob(getcwd() . '/cookies/*.txt') as $file) {
    $pointer = fopen($file, 'r');
    while (!feof($pointer)) {
        $row[] = fgets($pointer);
    }
}

var_dump($row);
```

Porém contem linhas desnecessárias no arquivo, eu preciso pegar apenas os `cookies`, olha o que me retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso apenas dos `cookies`, entendem?

Comment: Leia sobre a função [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php).

Comment: Ta blz. vou ver.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss posso responder minha propria pergunta?

Comment: Pode sim, sem problemas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Editei, vê se vc consegue me ajudar.

Comment: Quais dessas linhas seriam os cookies?

Comment: `_twitter_sess`, `ct0`, `auth_token`, `twid`, preciso dessses, prefixo e valores. entende?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234656/ler-conte%C3%BAdo-de-v%C3%A1rios-arquivos-txts-de-uma-determinada-pasta?noredirect=1#comment480437_234656), você deseja pegar apenas as linhas que contenham os valores de `_twitter_sess`, `ct0` e `auth_token`. Você pode armazenar esses valores em uma lista:

```
$tokens = ['_twitter_sess', 'ct0', 'auth_token'];
```

E verificar quais linhas possuem pelo menos um desses valores:

```
foreach (glob(getcwd() . '/cookies/*.txt') as $file) {
    $pointer = fopen($file, 'r');
    while (!feof($pointer)) {
        $line = fgets($pointer);

        foreach ($tokens as $token) {
            if (strpos($line, $token) !== false) {
                $row[] = $line;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, a linha em `$pointer` só será adicionada à lista se algum token definido em `$tokens` for encontrado na linha. Depois disso, você pode utilizar tanto expressão regular quanto separar a linha nos espaços em branco para extrair o valor desejado.

Comment: Testando... só um minuto, está com erro, vou tentar resolver

Comment: Pronto, era preciso ler a linha do arquivo antes da verificação, com a variável `$line`. Antes eu estava verificando o ponteiro, que não faz muito sentido.

Comment: Eu adicionei mais linhas, `$tokens = ['_twitter_sess', 'ct0', 'auth_token', 'twid'];` porem só está me retornando assim: http://prntscr.com/ggz52e, e percebi que não está listando todos os arquivos.

Comment: Você verificou se o retorno de `glob` é a lista com todos os arquivos?

Comment: Sim todos eles contém no arquivo, no caso ali você está verificando todos que são diferentes de `false` no caso, me retornará todos as linhas que são `TRUE / TRUE` porém não está retornando todos, apenas `_twitter_sess`, os dois primeiro, do arquivo 1 e do arquivo 2. E o resto não.

Comment: Tem como colocar o conteúdo dos arquivos em algum lugar para podermos replicar? Pode retirar dados potencialmente sensíveis, desde que não altere o formato do arquivo.

Comment: @PedroSilva outro erro meu, perdão. O `fgets` deve estar fora do laço que percorre os *tokens*, senão o conteúdo da linha é alterado de um *token* para o outro, por isso gerou um resultado inesperado. Já alterei na resposta e acredito que assim deva funcionar.

Comment: Boa, eu poderia ter percebido isso também, mas passou batido rsrs, obrigado, agora uma dúvida, posso usar esses cookies normalmente sem usar a global `$_COOKIES` ? não faz sentido eu salvar um arquivo contendo cookies e não utiliza-los.